# Flutter does not execute function code inside of then() of Future

Tags: firebase, flutter, future

For some odd reason the function code inside the then() is not executed. If the future successful, shouldn't the code execute inside of the then() function? Am I missing something or not understanding something?

I do get the print statements for `print('change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState: here');` and `print('change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState: here2');` but not for `print('change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState: $value');`

The goal of this code is to update the user password and receive an error message if any occur.

```
Stream<ChangePasswordState> _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState(
  ChangePasswordSubmitted event) async* {
String errorCode;
yield ChangePasswordState.changePasswordSubmitting();
try {
  print('change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState: here');
  await _userRepository
      .updateUserPassword(
          currentPassword: event.currentPassword,
          newPassword: event.newPassword)
      .then((value) async* {
    print('change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState: $value');
    if (errorCode == 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD') {
      yield ChangePasswordState.changePasswordFailure();
    } else {
      yield ChangePasswordState.changePasswordSuccess();
    }
  }).catchError((onError) async* {
    print('change_password_bloc error: $onError');
  });
  print('change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState: here2');
} catch (error) {
  yield ChangePasswordState.changePasswordFailure();
  print('change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState state error: $error');
}
```

}

Comment: You should stop using both await and .then(). Convert all of them to async/await and get rid of then()s. Also using async* inside a .then() function just blew my mind. That combination is probably creating a very weird outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing async and .then() is a bad idea. Please see my talk about it: https://youtu.be/t8LgA4zcW6M?t=1563

Also, the async* inside then is probably causing something really weird. It's not correct usage at all, it's not able to yield out anything there.

Here I got rid of the then, can you give it a try?

```
  Stream<ChangePasswordState> _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState(
      ChangePasswordSubmitted event) async* {
    String errorCode;
    yield ChangePasswordState.changePasswordSubmitting();
    try {
      print('change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState: here');
      try {
        await _userRepository
            .updateUserPassword(
            currentPassword: event.currentPassword,
            newPassword: event.newPassword);
        print(
            'change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState: $value');
        if (errorCode == 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD') {
          yield ChangePasswordState.changePasswordFailure();
        } else {
          yield ChangePasswordState.changePasswordSuccess();
        }
      } catch(e) {
        print('change_password_bloc error: $e');
      }
      print('change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState: here2');
    } catch (error) {
      yield ChangePasswordState.changePasswordFailure();
      print(
          'change_password_bloc _mapChangedPasswordSubmittedToState state error: $error');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the suggestion. I will try tonight.